# What is this FPS in Radiation Hazard's "Block Mesa 64" video?

Tags: game-identification

18 seconds into Radiation Hazard's video [Block Mesa 64](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sSi1ISUs0A), he mentions Super Mario 64 and Half Life while jokingly showing images of two different games. The left image obviously is from Donkey Kong 64, but what FPS game is the image on the right from?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one of the images on the store page for the original [Red Faction](https://store.steampowered.com/app/20530/Red_Faction/).